# How to create a function that adds 'and' to the -1 spot of any list that is passed to it

Tags: python-3.x

I have a little practice program I am trying to do. I am trying to create a function that adds 'and' to the -1 spot of any list that is passed to it.
I know what I have to do but I do not know how to do it.

With the insert I need to insert 'and' at the element -1 so something like modList.insert(-1,x)
Where the x is where I would be adding whatever line to do something like
(-1 + str('and'))
But that does not work.

This is what I have so far:

```
def modList(someList):
    someList.insert(-1, 'and')
    print(someList)

spam = ['Dog','Cat','Bat','Mouse']
modList(spam)
```

Output:  `['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bat', 'and', 'Mouse']`

Desired output:  `['Dog, Cat, Bat, and Mouse']`

Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: For example, assumimg that the list always contains at least two elements: `', '.join(spam[:-1]) + ', and ' + spam[-1]`

Comment: Just one string. I haven't seen the join (method?) used yet. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind modifying the list itself:

```
def insert_end(li):
    # note that this function is inplace, so no need to 'return li'
    li[-1] = 'and ' + li[-1]

li = ['a', 'b', 'c']
insert_end(li)
print(li)
>> ['a', 'b', 'and c']
```

If your desired output is a string (not modifying the list in place, so need to `return` the outputted string):

```
def insert_end(li):
    return ', '.join(string for string in li[:-1]) + ' and ' + li[-1]

li = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(insert_end(li))
>> 'a, b and c'
```

In order to get the actual output you posted (a list with 1 string), simply return a list from my last example:

```
def insert_end(li):
    return [', '.join(string for string in li[:-1]) + ' and ' + li[-1]]

li = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(insert_end(li))
>> ['a, b and c']
```

**UPDATE 1**
As @StevenSummers mentioned in the comments, you can simply do `', '.join(li[:-1])` instead of `', '.join(string for string in li[:-1])`. It behaves exactly the same.

**UPDATE 2**

As requested in the comments, a further explanation of the line 
 `', '.join(string for string in li[:-1]) + ' and ' + li[-1]`:

`string for string in li[:-1]`

This returns a generator object that iterates over the list and returns all of its elements except for the last one. You can see it in action here:

```
li = ['a', 'b', 'c']
generator = (string for string in li[:-1])
for s in generator:
    print(s)
>> 'a'
   'b'
```

Now we are calling `', '.join` on that generator object. `join` returns a string that is created by inserting the string that it is called upon between the elements of the iterable it received as an argument.

So now we have:

```
li = ['a', 'b', 'c']
generator = (string for string in li[:-1])
# remember that generator is going to return ('a', 'b')
print(', '.join(generator))
>> 'a, b'  # note that we get a string back, with `, ` between the elements in generator
```

The next part is pretty much straight forward.
We just need to add `'and '` and the last element of the list to our output string:

```
'a, b' + ' and ' + li[-1]
>> 'a, b and c`
```

Comment: Some of this stuff is out of my league I guess. Ha. Trying to follow as much as I can.

Comment: Have not seen the . . . li. . . thing yet. Could you explain exactly what it does? Or is it just a list name?

Comment: "li" is just variable name

Comment: The one that is closest to what I am looking for is the 2nd and 3rd one with the single string. Was I even close to accomplishing what I was trying to do? Heh.

Comment: @DylanR. `li` is just a variable name referencing the list, just like `spam` is in your question. You were pretty close, but you added the string `and` to the list instead of adding it to the last string in the list.

Comment: @DeepSpace Yeah, I see my mistake now. I just didn't know how to add it to the end of the last element in the list without getting an error code. Thanks for all the feed back guys!

Comment: @DeepSpace One more question could you explain what the line return [', '.join(string for string in li[:-1]) + ' and ' + li[-1]] is doing? Or more of the (string for string in li[:-1]) part. I get the jist of the line of code but that part is hazy.

Comment: I don't understand the need for `', '.join(string for string in li[:-1])` isn't `', '.join(li[:-1])` better?

Comment: @StevenSummers You are absolutely correct. I guess I overlooked it.

Comment: Wow this is amazing. Thank you guys so much for taking the time to do this for me, this is the one of nicest things people have done. I understand all of it now. Thanks again. I'm new to this website, do I have to mark this as "solved" to not get in trouble or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
>>> spam = ['Dog','Cat','Bat','Mouse']
>>> last = spam[-1]
>>> last = "and "+last
>>> spam[-1] = last
>>> spam
['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bat', 'and Mouse']
>>> " ,".join(spam)
'Dog ,Cat ,Bat ,and Mouse'
```

Comment: You want to join on `', '` though.

Comment: `spam[-1] = 'and ' + spam[-1]` would suffice, given that `li` is always a  list of strings..

Comment: So i just need to add the line . . .spam[-1] = 'and ' + spam[-1]. . . ?

Comment: I feel more comfortable with this approach to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
def modList(spam):
    var = 'and ' + spam.pop()
    spam.append(var)
    spamstr = ', '.join(spam)
    return spamstr
```